# Spring security authentication builder incorrect LDAP postfix

Tags: spring-boot, ldap, spring-boot-security

I am working on a Spring Boot project that handles security through Spring Boot's security module and authenticates users through an Active Directory using LDAP.

However, every single time I try to log in it uses the incorrect baseDN. The baseDN I want would be 'dc=wimpi,dc=net', but what I get is 'dc=wimpi,dc=net/dc=example,dc=com'. I am having troubles figuring out where the postfix comes from as it is not mentioned anywhere in my code. I am passing the baseDN as part of the url and apply it in the following piece of code:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception{
        builder.ldapAuthentication()
            .contextSource()
            .url(properties.getLdapURL())
            ...
}
```

Kind regards,

Comment: Share the ldap url (anonymise it if need), to investigate

Comment: ldap://<address>:10389/dc=wimpi,dc=net is what I pass as an argument for properties.getLdapURL().

Comment: I think there is something else. Can you send some log. Are you sure of your ldap structure?

Comment: Where are you seeing that base DN as `dc=wimpi,dc=net/dc=example,dc=com`?